# Is 'applicationContext' forbidden as a domain property name in Grails 2.4.3?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.4

After migrating from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.4.3, a domain class with a property named applicationContext throws exceptions when using that property in criteria queries.

```
class WebResource {
     String applicationContext
}

class ResourceService {
  public WebResource getResourceByContext(String ctx) {
     WebResource.withCriteria() {
         eq('applicationContext', ctx)
     }
  }
}
```

A call to getResourceByContext() throws an exception:

```
    org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: applicationContext of: org.mydomain.WebResource
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1995)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1970)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:518)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:534)
        at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:417)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.(CriteriaLoader.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1663)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1639)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:907)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:884)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_withCriteria_closure11.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:304)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.doInSession(Unknown Source)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:303)
        at org.mydomain.WebResource.withCriteria(WebResource.groovy)
```

Is having domain properties with the name 'applicationContext' not allowed in Grails 2.4.3?  I could not find a reference to this scenario being forbidden in the Grails release notes,  upgrade guides, or JIRA.  I have worked around this issue by renaming the field and changing GORM references to the new name:

```
class WebResource {
    String appContext
    appContext column: 'APPLICATION_CONTEXT'
    public String getApplicationContext() {
        return appContext
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(String c) {
        appContext = c
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the name clash with the Spring ApplicationContext I suspect you've found the best answer already - name the property something else and use a `mapping` definition to set the database column name. I would recommend you *don't* add the getter/setter pair but just use the property name `appContext` directly in your code, as there are more than likely places in Grails core or plugins that assume (quite reasonably in my opinion) that a property named `applicationContext` is the Spring object rather than anything else.

Don't fight the conventions unless you have to.